# Python unsupported operand type pyppeteer

Tags: python, python-3.x, node.js

Estou tentando utilizar o pyppeteer (um port de puppeteer para python, com basicamente a mesma sintaxe).

Quando tento `await page.mouse.click('.jfk-button-narrow', { 'button': 'left' })`, levanta-se o erro

```
 File "C:\Users\Windows 7\Desktop\Scripts\ScriptsPython\PrimevalBrowserManipulator.py", line 9, in main
    await page.mouse.click('.jfk-button-narrow', { 'button': 'left' })
  File "C:\Users\Windows 7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\input.py", line 302, in click
    await self.move(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Windows 7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\input.py", line 277, in move
    x = round(fromX + (self._x - fromX) * (i / steps))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

na tentativo de selecionar o botão 'permutar linguas' no Google Translator. Entretanto o script funciona perfeitamente se eu usar algo como `await page.mouse.click(1066.0625, 135, { 'button': 'left' })` em que eu escolho o exato pixel a ser clicado (o que não é nem um pouco prático). Então o que há de errado com o `.jfk-button-narrow`? É exatamente a classe de elemento do botão 'permutar línguas'.

Meu código:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ 'width': 1280, 'height': 560 })
    await page.goto('https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR')
    await page.mouse.click('.jfk-button-img', { 'button': 'left' })
    await page.screenshot({'path': r'C:\Users\Windows 7\Desktop\yes.png'})
    await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Eu chequei o [source](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/_modules/pyppeteer/input.html#Mouse.move) e aparentemente o port para python não aceita `id/class/name` de elemento porém apenas coordenadas de pixel na função `page.mouse.click`, todavia não estou certo.

Comment: Está dizendo que não é possível executar a subtração `self._x - fromX` quando `self._x` é uma _string_ e `fromX` é um _float_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fim de clicar em um element a partir de seu seletor CSS, é necessário utilizar a classe ElementHandle do pyppeteer implícita no page.click(selector) ao invés de page.mouse.click(coordinates). O código corrigido ficará:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ 'width': 1280, 'height': 560 })
    await page.goto('https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR')
    await page.click('.jfk-button-img', button='left')
    await page.screenshot({'path': r'C:\Users\Windows 7\Desktop\yes.png'})
    await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```